# How to define and persist emacs calc holidays?

Tags: emacs

**Background:**

I'm finding this Emacs calc lisp function to be extremely useful:

```
(calc-eval "badd(<Fri Jul 1, 2022>,1)") => "<Tue Jul 5, 2022>"
```

This function adds 1 day to the date and skips Monday Jul 4 because it is a US Federal holiday... This is very useful!

[I've been studying the only Emacs calc documentation I can find on Emacs calc date arithmetic](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/Business-Days.html).  I would like to enter data [these rules for US Federal holidays](https://www.commerce.gov/hr/employees/leave/holidays) into my `~/.emacs`.

1. Is this possible? The Emacs calc documentation (first link above) shows an example of the `newweek` and `date` features (are these functions? Where are they documented?) to specify the US thanksgiving holiday as the 4th Thursday of November. Some other US holidays are the 1st, 2nd or 3rd Monday in a certain month. How can we specify these holidays?
2. Assuming this is possible, how can we persist these holidays to my `~/.emacs` file? I tried using the `m m` command to save the holidays I data entered via the stack user interface and it did not save the holidays.

**Can you improve my workaround?**

Here is my attempt that works (but only for 2022):

```
(setq var-Holidays '(vec (var sat var-sat) (var sun var-sun)
                     (calcFunc-date (var y var-y) 12 25); christmas
                     (calcFunc-date (var y var-y) 1 1)  ; new years
                     (calcFunc-date (var y var-y) 7 4)  ; independence day
                     (calcFunc-date (var y var-y) 9 5)  ; labor day
                     (calcFunc-date (var y var-y) 10 10); columbus day
                     (calcFunc-date (var y var-y) 11 11); veterans day
                     (calcFunc-date (var y var-y) 11 24); thanksgiving
                     (calcFunc-date (var y var-y) 1 17) ; Martin Luther King
                     (calcFunc-date (var y var-y) 2 21) ; Washington Birthday
                     (calcFunc-date (var y var-y) 5 30) ; Memorial day
                     (calcFunc-date (var y var-y) 6 20)))
```

I tried data entering the fancy rule for thanksgiving from the documentation using the stack user-interface (instead of elisp) and received the correct results when evaluating `badd(<Wed Nov 23, 2022>,1)`. Then I then examined the lisp variable var-Holidays and saved it in my ~/.emacs... I received incorrect results when evaluating `badd(<Wed Nov 23, 2022>,1)` again after restarting emacs (it just echoed the original expression).

Can you improve upon this so

(a) I don't have to data enter all the holidays every time I start a new emacs session

(b) I don't have to update the holiday data (using rules like the thanksgiving rules) every year?

(c) I can accommodate the fact that if new year's day falls on a Saturday or Sunday, workers often have the following Monday off... This is the same rule for the US independence day (Jul 4).

Comment: Did you save your .emacs after adding tje lines? (^x^s)

Comment: Yes... I know this because I was receiving bogus results until I commented out varHolidays (saved .emacs again) and then tried it again and got the results expected when no holidays are defined (other than sat & sun).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have put in my ~/.emacs for US Holidays...

```
(setq var-Holidays '(vec (var sat var-sat)(var sun var-sun)))
(nconc var-Holidays '((+ (calcFunc-newweek (calcFunc-date (var y var-y) 11 7) 4) 21))) ; thanksgivng: 4 Thu in November
(nconc var-Holidays '((+ (calcFunc-newweek (calcFunc-date (var y var-y) 10 7) 1) 14))) ; Columbus day: second monday of October
(nconc var-Holidays '((+ (calcFunc-newweek (calcFunc-date (var y var-y) 1 7) 1) 14))) ; Martin Luther King: 3rd Monday in January
(nconc var-Holidays '((+ (calcFunc-newweek (calcFunc-date (var y var-y) 2 7) 1) 14))) ; Washington Birthday: 3rd Monday in February
(nconc var-Holidays '((- (calcFunc-newweek (calcFunc-date (var y var-y) 6 7) 1) 7))) ; Memorial day last Monday in May ... why does this not work?
(nconc var-Holidays '((+ (calcFunc-newweek (calcFunc-date (var y var-y) 5 7) 1) 28))) ; Memorial day last Monday in May... is this correct? 4th monday in May
(nconc var-Holidays '((calcFunc-newweek (calcFunc-date (var y var-y)  9 7) 1))) ; laborday: first monday of September
(nconc var-Holidays '((calcFunc-date (var y var-y) 6 20))) ; JunTeenth
(nconc var-Holidays '((calcFunc-date (var y var-y) 7 4))) ; independence day
(nconc var-Holidays '((calcFunc-date (var y var-y) 11 11))) ; vetran's day
(nconc var-Holidays '((calcFunc-date (var y var-y) 12 24))) ;christmas eve
(nconc var-Holidays '((calcFunc-date (var y var-y) 12 25))) ;christmas day
(nconc var-Holidays '((calcFunc-date (var y var-y) 1 1))) ;new yeaars day
```

Here are my test cases:

```
(list (calc-eval "badd(<Tue Dec 31, 2019>,1)") "skipped New Years day"
      (calc-eval "badd(<Fri Jan 14 2022>,1)")  "skipped MLK day"
      (calc-eval "badd(<Fri Feb 18, 2022>,1)") "skipped president's day"
      (calc-eval "badd(<Fri May 27, 2022>,1)") "skipped memorial day"
      (calc-eval "badd(<Fri Jun 17, 2022>,1)") "skipped june teenth"
      (calc-eval "badd(<Fri Jul 1 2022>,1)")   "skipped independence day"
      (calc-eval "badd(<Fri Sep 2, 2022>,1)")  "skipped memorial day"
      (calc-eval "badd(<Fri Oct 14, 2022>,1)") "skipped columbus day"
      (calc-eval "badd(<Thu Nov 10, 2022>,1)") "skipped veterans day"
      (calc-eval "badd(<Wed Nov 23, 2022>,1)") "skipped thanksgiving day"
      (calc-eval "badd(<Thu Dec 23, 2021>,1)") "skipped christmas eve"
      )
```

Let me attempt to explain the code for thanksgiving `‘newweek(date(y, 11, 7), 4) + 21` [from the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/Business-Days.html).. The function `newweek` (aka `calcFunc-newweek`) implements a truncate or floor type function that accepts a date and returns the previous date of the sunday of the same week. So we first compute first Sunday of November: `newweek(date(y,11,7))`. Using Nov 7 guarantees the `newweek` function will give us a Sunday in November and we won't get a Sunday in October. But then we want the first Thursday, not the first Sunday:  `newweek(date(y,11,7),4)`. (Thursday is the fourth day of the week if you count Sunday as day zero). Then we add 3 weeks (21 days) because we want the third Thursday of November...

This general strategy works for many U.S. holidays... But some fixed holidays (like Christmas & Independence) are a problem because we would like to conditionally adjust the date of the day off only if Christmas falls on a Saturday or Sunday...

Can anyone enhance this to accommodate these kinds of holidays?